# Adding nodes through a TikZ style, using double dash lines ``--``

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, tikz-node

I'm basically asking [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159417/how-can-i-add-nodes-through-a-tikz-style) question, because the answer there is not working for the case with `--` lines.

Say you have a line like so:

```
\draw (0,0) -- (3,3) node[sloped, midway,above]{Hey!};
```

Then is it possible to make a style such that the code below produces the same result as above?

```
\draw[heyEnd](0,0) -- (3,3);
```

I suspect that it should be very possible, because arrow tips makes this effect.

Full example:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{
      heyEnd/.style={
          every edge/.style={
              edge node={node[sloped, midway,above]{Hey!}},
              draw
            }
        }
    }

    %% Intended result:
    % \draw (0,0) -- (3,3) node[sloped, midway,above]{Hey!};

    %% This works:
    % \draw[heyEnd](0,0) edge (3,3);

    % This does not, but I want it to
    \draw[heyEnd](0,0) -- (3,3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(Possibly) related:

- [How can "execute at begin node" be used with special characters like curly braces? (or: how to raise node content)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88517/how-can-execute-at-begin-node-be-used-with-special-characters-like-curly-brace)
- [TikZ: When will I need to use edge and how does it differ from the conventional path draw command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314301/tikz-when-will-i-need-to-use-edge-and-how-does-it-differ-from-the-conventional)

Comment: is edge the same as "--" ? Probably you have to do some style settings here as well (when possible).

Comment: I don't think that `edge` is equivalent to `--`. If it is supposed to be equivalent, then I've discovered a bug, heh :) I don't know when one should be used in favour of the other. I do, however, know that `--` is often used and I'd like to know how to do this. Mostly for educational purposes.

Comment: @albert [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314301/tikz-when-will-i-need-to-use-edge-and-how-does-it-differ-from-the-conventional) is an explanation of `edge` vs `--`. They are not supposed to be equivalent :)

Comment: From the Ti*k*Z manual: "Like a node the edge generated by the edge operation is not part of the main path, but is added only later." Maybe this is the reason...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik That might very well be the reason. I'd still want to know how to do it on `--` paths using styles :)

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman Sorry, but I have no idea :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't now if that's the answer you are looking for but you can of course achieve the same for `--` lines with decorations.

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{
      heyEnd/.style={
          every edge/.style={
              edge node={node[sloped, midway,above]{Hey!}},
              draw
            }
        },
     heyMark/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
     mark=at position 0.5 with {\node[midway,above,sloped]{Hey!}; }}}}  
    }

    %% Intended result:
    % \draw (0,0) -- (3,3) node[sloped, midway,above]{Hey!};

    %% This works:
    \draw[heyEnd](0,0) edge (3,3);

    % This works now
    \draw[heyMark](4,0) -- (7,3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]